How to Replace the Default Logo in Venia Theme with Magento 2 Logo in PWA Setup?
EDITED : I’m working with the Magento2 PWA setup using the Venia theme and need to replace the default Venia logo with the Magento2 logo. I’ve tried looking through the theme files but am not sure how to properly override the Venia logo with the Magento2 logo.
Can anyone guide me on the correct way to replace the logo in the Venia theme? Specifically, I’m looking for best practices on how to override the default logo so that it displays the Magento2 logo instead.
Thanks in advance for your help!

the path of logo is
packages/venia-ui/libcomponents/Logo/logo.svg, and if you to update the file name you can update the logo.js file.
https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/tree/develop/packages%2Fvenia-ui%2Flib%2Fcomponents%2FLogo

hello Faouzi Yahyaoui , thanks for reply, but my issue is i want to replace venia theme logo with magento2 logo in PWA...
